# How to Select Corresponding div for given button?

Tags: jquery

Here I have five buttons and five divs. If I click the first button then some data should be filled in first div only, not the others. The same goes for the consecutive buttons. I am doing this in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").each(function () {
        // code  here to put some data in relative div
    });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 5</button>

<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that if you want this to happen when the buttons are clicked you should use the `click()` method, not `each()`.

To make it work you can use the `index()` method to find the index of the clicked button and the `eq()` method to relate that index to the relevant `.myDiv`. Try this:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).index('button');
  $('.myDiv').eq(index).text('clicked button ' + (index + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Button 5</button>

<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```